# How can I add divider between action Items in Toolbar

Tags: android

I want to design a toolbar like:.

[image: img1]

I have done most of it but having some problem.

I don't know how to make a divider between the `toolbars` items and also having no idea how to set a counter variable attached to the  action button that increment as  order takes place like given in the picture.

Any suggestions?

Comment: divider could be an image and counter variable is shown in `textview`

Comment: @MrNeo can you show me Example?

Comment: You should try it yourself before asking on Stackoverflow, bro ^^.

Comment: Check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place your layout like below:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/..."
    android:showAsAction="always."
    android:icon="@drawable/..."
    android:title="@string/..."
    android:actionLayout="@layout/your_layout_here"/>
```

or

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/..."
    android:showAsAction="always."
    android:icon="@drawable/..."
    android:title="@string/..."
    android:actionViewClass="your_class"/>
```

where "your_class" - class which inflate and implement your view with separator

Comment: you mean i need to create a separate layout and then set that layout to the item in menu as  android:actionLayout="@layout/your_layout_here" in the first solution?

Comment: Yes. And then create optionMenu as usual

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a custom toolbar. Add your views between the toolbar's opening and closing tags.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dip"
        android:background="#ff0000">

        <!-- the back button -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="onBackButtonClick"
            android:paddingLeft="16dip"
            android:paddingRight="16dip"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_back" />

        ...

        <!-- the devider -->
        <View
            android:layout_width="1dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#ffffff" />


        <ImageView .../>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```